# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when calling remote interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, struts, javabeans

I have a JavaEE application running on Glassfish 4.0. I use Stuts 1.3, therefore i have to call the remote interface of a bean. When i'm calling the remote interface i get the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.mark.personbean.PersonDataBeanRemote.setLoginDatas(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Long;)V

l know what should it mean, but in my case, that makes no sense.
I have already:

- restarted the server
- cleaned the cache
- checked the classpathes
- checked the method
- tried to modify the method, save, clean and build and redeploy
- I even istalled an other version of glassfish, and tried
  to run on that, but with the same result

I am really desperate, and confused now. What else could I do?

Comment: Your copy of PersonDataBeanRemote inside Glassfish is too old.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Thank you for the tip, but unfortunately the problem is something else. My copy of PersonDataBeanRemote can't be too old, because I did all the things I mentioned above, plus undeployed, and deployed again manually. The program worked fine, the method worked, but I have changed something completly different, and it doesn't work anymore. I suspect, some descriptor file changed, but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Then go back in your version control system to the latest version that worked and see what was changed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  I don't have a version control system. I thought it does not necessary for an easy school project. I was wrong. I commented out every line of code I touched, or even look at after the last working version. Still got the same error. But I have changed the name of the java class, and it magically works now. It must be some weird caching problem, but I have still no idea what it is.

Comment: This is exactly why you use version control.  If the name change works, then you probably have deployed multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

Find the source file and import it to application. With method modification in com.mark.personbean.PersonDataBeanRemote.setLoginDatas.java
I have done in my modbus application.
It worked fine.